# cron is added but not executing current time

Tags: linux, cron, chef-infra, chef-recipe

> following is my recipe I am trying to create a new text file with current time and date

```
cron 'cron_disply_time' do
  minute '*/1'
  command "echo #{Time.new.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")} > /home/vagrant/learn-cron/cookbooks/t.txt"
  action :create
end
```

> Its always taking the time when the job was added

```
*/1 * * * * echo 2020-05-07 14:06 > /home/vagrant/learn-cron/cookbooks/t.txt
```

> can some please let me know how can I make it executable with the recipe only

Comment: did you look at the cron logs or syslogs to understand what is the problem?

Comment: Do you expect it to be executed every minute or every hour? May be you just didn't wait long enough for it to execute?

Comment: Let me rephrase my question added more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cron 'cron_disply_current_time' do
  minute '*/1'
  command 'NOW=$(date +"%T") && sudo echo "Current time:"  $NOW > /home/vagrant/current_time.txt'
  action :create
end
```

> `date` will show the current date
>
> `NOW=$(date +"%T")` will show the time
>
> `sudo echo "Current time:"  $NOW > /home/vagrant/current_time.txt'` will add "Current time:"  11:14:19 into current_time.txt file

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`cron` resource generates a static file with the command inside it, so yes, it will put 1 and the same string into the file.

In bash current time one can get by calling `date`

```sh
$ date
Fri May  8 09:58:39 EEST 2020
```

So you can use this function inside your cron to get the current time like this:

```rb
cron 'cron_disply_time' do
  minute '*'
  command 'date "+%F %H:%M" > /home/vagrant/learn-cron/cookbooks/t.txt'
  action :create
end
```